# Problem with static files in django heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I have sam problems this static files in django. I sucsesfull deploy django app to heroku and this site workin **https://timon-webchat.herokuapp.com/**, but how you can see without any styles or images. But if runing python manage.py runserver local all good and I can see styles, js-codes and images
Please tell me what's wrong here is mine setings.py file:

```
"""
Django settings for web_chat project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.7.

For more information o
n this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
import os
import django_heroku



BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '+*yv5wtriwzs91yk!gpu27r!p+b1063n26bpjf79+=236yu4%t'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_gravatar',
    'app_chat',
    'acounts',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'acounts.User'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy("main")
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy("login")

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # Simplified static file serving.
    # https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    )


ROOT_URLCONF = 'web_chat.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'web_chat.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR/ 'static'0
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'asets/'),
]


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'media')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

In directory statifiles i have directorys: css, js, admin, app_chat
in thare i have my styles js codes and images. So what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for Django to process your static files, you should run `python manage.py collectstatic`. Heroku should already do this for you though. Heroku doesn't automatically serve your static files, which is why I recommend you use the `whitenoise` package. It allows your Django app to auto-serve static files with no additional config.

See the docs for Django here: http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html

Also add `whitenoise` to your `requirements.txt`

Comment: thank you this is help, but this strange because I try it before and this didn't work

Comment: Make sure that `whitenoise` is in your requirements and that you have configured Django to serve static files with Whitenoise